# PHP is not working when function parameter is assigned to variable

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have a problem which is really brain-cracking. I would like to use the $this variable inside a function. As long as it is the function parameter variable, there is no problem. But when I change the code to assign it inside, it is no longer working (blank page when direct opened, AJAX responds with Internal Server Error). The rest of the code inside the function uses the variable $this, and perfectly works in the second way.

The full script is an AJAX e-mail sender for a WordPress site, using global $wpdb.

Am i missing something or is it too late night to see the mistake? :)

**NOT WORKING**

```
function lookup_product($in){
    $this = $in;

    echo $this;
}
```

**WORKING**

```
function lookup_product($this){

    echo $this;
}
```

Comment: `$this` is reserved in PHP to refer to the class instance when used inside a class method. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` is a predefined variable in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Change the var `$this` to something else.